# Can someone convert this circuit from 12VDC to 6VDC

Tags: digital-logic, design

[image]

It is a small sensor which activates relay when there's dark.

I just want that circuit to work with 5Vdc or 6Vdc.

Comment: @brhans do you want to make that an answer, I'd feel bad posting an answer myself that was a duplicate of your comment.